# Raspberry pi play wav file

Tags: java, audio, raspberry-pi2

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

class DataManage{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        MusicControl musicControler;
        File clip;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int data;

        while(true){
            data = scan.nextInt();

            clip = new File(new StringBuffer().append("LaunchPad/music/").append(data).append(".wav").toString());
            musicControler = new MusicControl(clip);        
            musicControler.start();
        }
    }
}

import java.io.File;

import javax.sound.sampled.*;

class MusicControl extends Thread{

    private Clip clip;
    private File sound;
    private FloatControl volume;

    public MusicControl(File sound){
            this.sound = sound;
            musicSetup();
    }

    public void run(){
        try{    
            clip.start();
            Thread.sleep(clip.getMicrosecondLength()/1000);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);  
        }
    }

    public void musicSetup(){
        try{
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(sound));
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to play a sound in my Raspberry pi2.
This program works really well in Window7.
However, it works strange in the Raspberry pi2.
When I start the program, it works well until it counts 8.
If it plays more than 8 times, it prints

```
javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailaleException: line with format PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian not supported.
```

How can I fix it? Please give me a hand.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in this method

```
public MusicControl(File Sound){
        sound = Sound;
        musicSetup();
}
```

You are defining a variable like `File Sound` which is 2 types and no name. You have to replace the `Sound` with a name for the variable.

Comment: 'Sound' is just a object name from DataManage class!

Comment: Sorry my bad.. i was just making a Test program.. so i didn't really care about that problem..^^